# Return date value from nth week of month in SQL Developer without creating function

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a select query which has to return date.
Eg: if i need 4th week of friday for current month, then i am expecting 2019-09-27.

But my challenge is i don't want to use any function.

I have tried below code

```
select next_day( (trunc(to_date('nov','mon'),'mm')-1), 'fri' ) + 21 from dual
```

Above code gives last week's date, but i am expecting any week's date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you determine which week is in a month.

If want the first week to be the iso-week where any day of the week is in the month:

- `TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' )` you will get the first day of the month.
- `TRUNC( first_day_of_month, 'IW' )` will truncate the date to the start of the iso-week (i.e. Monday).
- `NEXT_DAY( monday_of_week_including_first_day_of_month, 'FRIDAY' )` will find the friday in the iso-week containing the first day of the month.
- If you want the Friday of the 4th iso-week then add 3 weeks:

I.e.:

```sql
SELECT NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 'IW' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'FRIDAY' ) + 3 * INTERVAL '7' DAY AS friday4,
       NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 'IW' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'MONDAY' ) + 0 * INTERVAL '7' DAY AS monday1,
       NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 'IW' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'SUNDAY' ) + 0 * INTERVAL '7' DAY AS sunday1
FROM   DUAL;
```

> ```
> FRIDAY4   | MONDAY1   | SUNDAY1  
> :-------- | :-------- | :--------
> 20-SEP-19 | 26-AUG-19 | 01-SEP-19
> ```

If you want to use iso-weeks but start where the first week of the month is the iso-week which contains the first Thursday of the month (as is used to calculate when a week is within an iso-year) then you need to use some additional logic to determine this:

```sql
SELECT NEXT_DAY(
         TRUNC( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 'IW' )
         + CASE
           WHEN TRUNC( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 'IW' ) + INTERVAL '3' DAY >= TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' )
           THEN INTERVAL '-1' DAY
           ELSE INTERVAL '6' DAY
           END,
         'FRIDAY'
       ) + 3 * INTERVAL '7' DAY
       AS friday4,
       NEXT_DAY(
         TRUNC( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 'IW' )
         + CASE
           WHEN TRUNC( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 'IW' ) + INTERVAL '3' DAY >= TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' )
           THEN INTERVAL '-1' DAY
           ELSE INTERVAL '6' DAY
           END,
         'MONDAY'
       ) + 0 * INTERVAL '7' DAY
       AS monday4,
       NEXT_DAY(
         TRUNC( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 'IW' )
         + CASE
           WHEN TRUNC( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 'IW' ) + INTERVAL '3' DAY >= TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' )
           THEN INTERVAL '-1' DAY
           ELSE INTERVAL '6' DAY
           END,
         'SUNDAY'
       ) + 0 * INTERVAL '7' DAY
       AS sunday4
FROM   DUAL;
```

> ```
> FRIDAY4   | MONDAY1   | SUNDAY1  
> :-------- | :-------- | :--------
> 27-SEP-19 | 02-SEP-19 | 08-SEP-19
> ```

If you want start the counting from the first day of the month (regardless of which day of the week it is):

```sql
SELECT NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'FRIDAY' ) + 3 * INTERVAL '7' DAY AS friday4,
       NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'MONDAY' ) + 0 * INTERVAL '7' DAY AS monday1,
       NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'SUNDAY' ) + 0 * INTERVAL '7' DAY AS sunday1
FROM   DUAL;
```

> ```
> FRIDAY4   | MONDAY1   | SUNDAY1 
> :-------- | :-------- | :--------
> 27-SEP-19 | 02-SEP-19 | 01-SEP-19
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=aabd28a5dad67e1fb04059ff74af1c8c)*

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option; `calendar` CTE I created refers to this September.

```
SQL> set ver off
SQL>
SQL> with calendar as
  2    (select trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + level - 1 datum
  3     from dual
  4     connect by level <= 30
  5    ),
  6  inter as
  7    (select datum,
  8       to_char(datum, 'w') week_in_month,
  9       to_char(datum, 'dy', 'nls_date_language=english') day
 10     from calendar
 11    )
 12  select datum
 13  from inter
 14  where day = '&day'
 15    and week_in_month = &week;
Enter value for day: tue
Enter value for week: 2

DATUM
----------
10.09.2019

SQL> /
Enter value for day: fri
Enter value for week: 3

DATUM
----------
20.09.2019

SQL>
```

Comment: This will always have the first day of the first week of the month as the first day of the month so weeks will start on a different day of the week depending on which month this is called in. Not an issue if this is the expected behaviour but if you are expecting weeks to start on Monday (or whichever day is appropriate for your territory) then the behaviour may be unexpected.

Comment: Also, you have hard-coded the month to have 30 days. You could use `connect by trunc(DATE '2019-08-01', 'mm') + level - 1 < trunc(DATE '2019-08-01', 'mm') + INTERVAL '1' MONTH` instead.

Comment: @MT0: 30 days - sure, this (as every September) has 30 days :) . I presumed that `w` week format mask is what the OP wants, as they said " 4th week of friday for current month" - current month is September 2019, 4th week's Friday was 3 days ago on 27th.